# Do companies who go public lower their R&D spending as a result?

Tags: economics

Eric Ries talks in an [interview](https://youtu.be/x6DYUanRdGE?t=503) with Ezra Klein about how there are studies that show that when a company goes public, it usually lowers their R&D spending afterwards. Is this is accurate representation of the academic literature?

Comment: This appears to be ignoring the fact that companies that are just being founded will often pour the vast majority of their resources into R&D, in order to develop their first product.  Once they are established well enough to "go public" they are usually past this point.

Comment: @DanielRHicks : Eric Ries does point to a study that looks for firms of similar size, age etc to control for factors like that. Infortunately, the part of the interview isn't easily quoted.

Comment: Not sure what the overall consensus is, but here's a study supporting the opposite: https://www.federalreserve.gov/econres/feds/files/2018068pap.pdf